# Applying clearfix to all div to prevent container collapse

Tags: html, css

Is it good idea to add `clearfix` to all `div` elements to prevent container collapse situations?

Or to use it just on classes like this ?

```
<div class="container">
   More div elements...
</div>

.container::after {
 clear: both;
 content: “”;
 display: table;
}
```

Comment: There is no point in using it where it is not needed. You're just giving the server more to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)

Comment: I would stop using floats too - you can use flex now and it is a lot easier to manipulate positions with flex

Answer (score 3):

You use a `clearfix` only when the child elements are using floats, to avoid collapse situation. Otherwise no need to use `clearfix`

```
.clearfix::after{
content:"";
display:table;
width:100%;
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: `width:100%` part is not needed, IMHO. `clear:both` is enough to push this pseudo element below both left and right floats.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chandra Shekar worte, you should only use it when using floats. But note one detail *if*  you use it:

In the CSS rule you posted, you wrote: `content: “”;` Those are typographical quotes which won't work as desired. Change that to regular quotes, like `content: "";`, or also single (non-typographical) quotes like `content: '';`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's a terrible idea, for the following reasons:

1. Clearfix is a hack. It was introduced as a workaround for
   another hack — using floats as a main block layout tool, which they
   were never meant to be (as well as tables!). When float are used for
   what they were meant to (incut illustrations, tables etc. in long
   texts) the fact they cross the boundaries of blocks (in both
   directions, from outside to inside and vice versa) is a feature, not
   bug. Clearing everything inselectively would lead to ugly holes in
   the document, text would not nicely flow around floats anymore.
2. Clearfixes add pseudo elements to the blocks. These pseudo
   elements have zero size and are invisible if the hack is used for
   what it was invented (to make the block contain nested floats and,
   optionally, margins of its children). But it is not definitely the
   case in other situations. For example, if you turn such block into
   Flexbox container and set it `justify-content:space-between`, you
   would get unwanted space at the end of the container.
   It's because this pseudo element would turn into flex element and
   it would follow Flexbox placement rules, affecting the
   position of other elements. Same for Grid layout.
3. Clearfix hacks based on the `clear` property are not ideal
   even for for containing floats! The 'clearfixed' blocks stay in the  same [block formatting context (BFC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) as their neighbourhood, so they may be affected by *other* floats in the document (e.g. a floated previous column). The other approach for containing floats, based on creating the new BFC (mostly used in
   form of `overflow:hidden`, but there are other alternatives, each
   with its own strengths and downsides) is in general much more
   reliable. Please check out this Codepen demo that compares the
   effect of different solutions to containing floats problem:
   https://codepen.io/SelenIT/details/qrORXm/.

Personally, I'd recommend not using floats for layout at all, so no 'clearfixing' would be needed for anything. Flexbox has much more layout possibilities than floats ever had, and browser support for it became [extremely good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) now. Use clearfixes as a last resort, if no other way to solve the specific layout problem can help you.